# Ctrl+Alt+L in BluePrism not working

Tags: blueprism

Used "^%{L}" for performing cntrl+Alt+L in BluePrism but the required window is not opening up, the command is working fine in general when executed manually.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to make sure that you are following the appropriate steps to send keys to an application. The recommendation is to first activate the application (this ensures the keys are sent to the proper application), then use a wait stage (this ensures that BluePrism is sending the keys at the right time; i.e. when the application is ready to accept keys), then use the navigation stage on the **root application** where the send keys is located, something like this:

[image]

(If you are typing in a specific field in the window, then use an additional Focus navigation stage on the Field itself before sending keys).

Within the navigation stage, you have two possible options to send keys:

1. Global Send Keys
2. Global Send Key Events

[image]

### Global Send Keys

You can find the [official guide](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/2018-04/Surface%20Automation%20-%20Advanced%20Training%20.pdf) (section 10.2) on the [BluePrism portal](https://portal.blueprism.com/learning/surface-automation). It doesn't really detail the sending of combination keys for Global Send Keys, but you really have to do it like this:

```
^(%l)
```

Do note that if you send `^(%L)`, this is similar to sending Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L. The parens indicate that for the keying of `%l`, Shift is held down. The above is equivalent to `^(%(l))`. Normal keys do not require braces either, and they cause issues if used in Global Send Key Events (i.e. `{L}` means Shift+L in Global Send Keys, but will give you an error in Global Send Key Events).

The relevant part of the guide:
[image]

So what you were doing with `^%{L}` didn't really make sense to BluePrism. It was probably sending Ctrl+Alt, then separately Shift+L (I cannot really confirm this, but this is my guess following testing on BluePrism which definitely show it doesn't work, however).

### Global Send Key Events

You can find the documentation in the same guide and section I linked earlier. This time, [it does show exactly how to send combination keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoGkz.png), so for your case, the other option with Global Send Key Events will be:

```
<{CTRL}<{ALT}l>{ALT}>{CTRL}
```

I don't really like Global Send Key Events because it's longer to type and you have to be careful about more things, but essentially, it becomes easier if you type the opening and closing syntax before proceeding with the next key. For example to do the above, it's easier to first type `<{CTRL}>{CTRL}`, then insert the ALT part in the middle: `<{CTRL}<{ALT}>{ALT}>{CTRL}`, then insert the `l` (do note here that `l` and `L` are equivalent here, which is also weird considering that they are not in Global Send Keys).

Answer (score 0):

I presume that it's a GLOBAL SEND KEY EVENT value that you're looking for.

This is shift+I action value:

```
"<{SHIFT}I>{SHIFT}"
```

I would try for ctrl+Alt+L maybe something like this:

```
"<{CTRL}{ALT}L>{CTRL}"
```

the "<" & ">" is Push down & Release

Comment: This is not how you use `{ALT}` in Global Send Key Events.

Answer (score 0):

Global Send Keys is going to send the keys to whatever application has focus on screen, so I would recommend:

1. Set focus on the desired window by either using a Navigate stage to "Activate Application" or "Global Mouse Click".
2. Use Global Send Keys

[image: Snip of BluePrism Code]

Keep in mind that a Global Mouse Click could again result in something unexpected as its sending the event directly to the screen, and another application/window might be covering the area you've just clicked.

For more info on Global Send Keys and Global Send Keys Event I would read the BluePrism manual for this: [Send Keys and Send Key Events](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/2018-02/Guide%20to%20Send%20Keys%20and%20Send%20Key%20Events.pdf)

It might also be worthwhile studying some surface automation principles as it can help get you a better understanding of what these Global actions are doing: [Introduction to Surface Automation](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/2017-12/v5%20Introduction%20to%20Surface%20Automation.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

1. Activate the application using navigate stage.
2. Add a 1sec wait between activate and send keys.
3. Use global send keys event. <{ctrl}<{alt}L>{alt}>{ctrl}

Answer (score -1):

Ensure you are using the root element in Application Modeller (the first at the top of the list) and not any of the child elements. Use a navigate stage with that element and either Global Send Key or Global Send Key Event action. The syntax "^%{L}" is otherwise correct, although you don't say what is it that you are trying to automate (Excel, Word, IE, Citrix...??).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Global SendKey instead of G.S.Events. I.e. SHIFT+HOME = "+({HOME})"
regular brackets needed for blue prism to understand where to release Shift ("+").